# Accessing a method from a property

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have the following:

```html
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, a, list_of_Bar)
    self.a = a
    self.b = list_of_Bar
    
  def do_something(self, thing1, thing2):
    return thing1 * thing2 * a

class Bar:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
 
  @property  
  def z(self):
    return ???.do_something(self.x, self.y)
```

Is there some mechanism for ??? that will allow me to reference the instance of Foo that contains an instance of Bar?  Will it work if Foo.b is a list of instances of Bar instead of a single instance?  Or, if I wanted to move do_something to Bar, is there a way Bar could access Foo.a?

Comment: Pass the instance of Foo to the instance of Bar... But this seems like a design problem, fundamentally

Comment: Indeed, I'm just struggling with how to express the problem in generic terms.  More broadly, I'm dealing with different variants of Bar that will treat the result of do_something  differently in z.  In the main application I want to iterate over list_of_Bar and pull z for each, so I could pass the instance of Foo, but that seems brute force.

Comment: In the future, please tag all python related questions with the generic [python] tag. It will at the very least help your question gain more traction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You property z, is really just a method in a instance of Bar. That means that it has access to all the attributes and methods in the instance of Bar through `self.*`

So what your question is really asking is, is there a way for an instance of a class to know what other objects have references to it. There is not a general mechanism to point back to any references out there pointing to an instance.

You can build something yourself, with the cooperation of Bar's and Foo's (or whatever object is holding a reference to a Bar). You would need to maintain a list in Bar of things that pointed to it, and when Foo added or removed a reference to the instance of Bar would have to call routines in Bar to add or remove itself from Bars internal list as Foo's added or removed references to Bar's. Foo would have to pass the Foo's `self` as a parameter of the method so that the Bar could add the reference to its internal list.

This would imply references back and forth between the two classes.

Be careful about this though. Cyclic references can cause issues with the Garbage Collector. The GC determines when things can be cleaned up by reference counting and circular references like those just described can sometimes prevent objects from being cleaned up. The GC can handle some forms of cyclic references or it would never be able to manage doubly linked lists and the like, but I know there are some forms (maybe when the loops of links are bigger?) that can challenge it. These linked but otherwise orphaned objects just live on in the background and their memory never gets released. Not really a problem for most short lived programs though.

If that is a concern for you there are ways to manage that. Python added a `weakref` to make this kind of thing easier. You make the one (not both) of the references a weakref. The weakref breaks the cycle of references as far as the GC is concerned which allows it to clean up. See docs on [weakref here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html).